# Sub domain different host

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, dns-zone

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 with AD, DNS, DHCP, IIS.

I am hosting a domain example.com and have one public IP from my ISP.

Port 80 is forwarded to IIS server. I have a NAS server and created a host name (nas) in DNS Server, pointed it to NAS private IP and I can access it locally via nas.example.com

Now I want to be able to access nas.example.com from outside of my own network.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot point a domain to a different port, however you would have to forward another port to the nas.
The only method that I can think of is to redirect the request to the other server like a proxy.

Comment: Like a **reverse proxy**, to be exact. There are countless guides on the internet, but this one looks nice and easy: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis